# How to get the value of chart which is been clicked in click event of highcharts

Tags: highcharts

How to get the value of chart which is been clicked in click event of highcharts

```
 "series": [
        {
            "name": "Requests",
            "colorByPoint": true,
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "Pending",
                    "y": 62,
                    "drilldown": "Pending"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Completed",
                    "y": 20,
                    "drilldown": "Completed"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Rejected",
                    "y": 18,
                    "drilldown": "Rejected"
                },
            ]
        }
    ],
    "drilldown": {
        "series": [
            {
                "name": "Requests",
                "id": "Pending",
                "data": [
                    [
                        "New Version",
                        21
                    ],
                    [
                        "HotFixes",
                        13
                    ],
                        ],
                  point: {
                        events: {
                                click: function() {
                                        alert("here we are");
                                }
                        }
                        }

            },
```

Here suppose i am clicked on "New Version", so how could i fetch the value in the click event that "New Version" is been clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to paste the function within `plotOptions` Not within `series`, but just in the main configuration

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

This alerts the given category on click, plus the y value.

You can find more information in the [Highcharts API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.point.events/). This API also links to [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-click/) showing how to use the alert function.

Summarizing, your code should look like this (even if what you gave us is not the full code). You might need to alter the alert function a little bit to display what you want exactly.

```
 plotOptions: {
        series: {
            cursor: 'pointer',
            point: {
                events: {
                    click: function () {
                        alert('Category: ' + this.category + ', value: ' + this.y);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
 "series": [
    {
        "name": "Requests",
        "colorByPoint": true,
        "data": [
            {
                "name": "Pending",
                "y": 62,
                "drilldown": "Pending"
            },
            {
                "name": "Completed",
                "y": 20,
                "drilldown": "Completed"
            },
            {
                "name": "Rejected",
                "y": 18,
                "drilldown": "Rejected"
            },
        ]
    }
],
"drilldown": {
    "series": [
        {
            "name": "Requests",
            "id": "Pending",
            "data": [
                [
                    "New Version",
                    21
                ],
                [
                    "HotFixes",
                    13
                ],
                    ],
        },
```